# Spark from SQL External source automatically updated

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a simple question. I am loading a large extrenal source of data using Spark

```
Map<String, String> options = new HashMap<String, String>();
options.put("url", "jdbc:postgresql:dbserver");
options.put("dbtable", "schema.tablename");

DataFrame myDF= sqlContext.read().format("jdbc"). options(options).load();
```

I wanted to know if my external sql database is updated the changes will reflect to my data frame or I again need to call load function to populate the dataframe.

In the case I need to call load function again,is there any more efficient way in Spark which can update the data frame when external sources change?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is doesn't but details are relatively subtle. In general Spark cannot event guarantee a consistent state of the database. Each executor fetches its own part of the data inside separate transaction so if data is actively modified there is no guarantee all executors will see the same state of the database.

This becomes even more complicated when you consider explicit and implicit (shuffle files) caching and possible executors failures and cache evictions. So if you want a consistent view of the database then it has to be supported by both model and queries. In general it means that data source should support consistent point-in-time queries and every query you execute from Spark should use specific timestamp.

The last question is really hard to answer without knowing more about your use case but there are at least two problems:

- Spark data structures are not very well suited for small incremental updates. Cost of scheduling are relatively high and incremental unions introduce different problems like long lineages and complex partition management
- there is no vendor independent method to monitor database changes